# Uploading necessary dependencies for Angular2 App into a web host

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, angular

I am new to `Angular2` and have a bit of confusion with the `node.js` and the angular2 framework functioning and relationship.

I can run my app with the lite-server on localhost, but my problem is uploading the app to the hosting service.
There are not any tutorials or guides of what to do when the app is ready, so I have been trying to make a bundle with webpack, but I am not successful. 
I know it is a BAD practice to upload all `node_modules` installed by `npm` but am I correct trying to make such bundle?

Another clarification would be if my app can run my app just by uploading the `html`, `css` and `js` files (including those in the node_modules)? or do I need to configure a host that allows `Node.js` to run my application?

Answer (score 1):

In Angular2 if you use Typescript you need transpile the webapp, this transpile put the files in /dist folder.
If you use ES6, you use the app in the root folder of you develop.

I you open the "index.html" in your browser of you /dist folder, the app in angular2 work.

In the index.html you have this code

```
System.import('system-config.js').then(function () {
  System.import('main');
}).catch(console.error.bind(console));
```

In your main.js of the /dist you have this code

```
var _1 = require('./app/');
```

In this folder require you have this (for example)

```
var ng_fire_component_1 = require('./ng-fire.component');
```

this require call to your principal component of the webbapp... In this logic your app run with only open the index.html when ng-fire.component is your root component.

---

In node you only need create a web-server, this webserver (if use express js ) you need call the index.html

```
router.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('yourAPPfolder/index.html');
});
```

and your webApp its run again when you open the www.yourweb.com/ or localhost:yourPort/

For the last question, if use the server, you have import the folder /dist in this folder you have all file who need.

I recomend the angular ci (https://cli.angular.io) for work with angular2 ... if you need other vendor file or vendor folder you can add in the file angular-cli-build.js

for example:

```
    /* global require, module */

var Angular2App = require('angular-cli/lib/broccoli/angular2-app');

    module.exports = function(defaults) {
      return new Angular2App(defaults, {
        vendorNpmFiles: [
          'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
          'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
          'zone.js/dist/*.js',
          'es6-shim/es6-shim.js',
          'reflect-metadata/*.js',
          'rxjs/**/*.js',
          '@angular/**/*.js'
        ]
      });
    };
```